# IIS server redirect locations

Tags: iis, asp-classic, redirect

I got a asp site hosted in a iis server. In the server there is a virtual folder products and whenever a url like xyz.com/products/abc_11.asp is provided it is forwared to xyz.com/product.asp?id=11 page.

I would like to know from where we can change that settings?

These settings or tasks can be done from where?

Thnx

Comment: Which version of IIS? Are you using ISAPI_Rewrite? More details please.

Comment: I dont know the version of IIS on server but its iis 7 on my local computer

Comment: OK, so is there a file called httpd.ini in your web root folder?

Comment: @KoolKabin: Its difficult to help you when you appear to know little about the configuration of your own web site. For example 2 days ago Mark B asked "Are you using ISAPI_Rewrite?", whats the answer to this? Do you have any form of URL rewriter installed?

Comment: In my server i do not find any place from where i check that. I checked file manager, application pool and some other folders but i dont find any mark of ISAPI_Rewrite. How can i know that it is there or not?

Comment: Thxn for help. It has been working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the folder "products" or file "abc_11.asp" physically exist on the webserver? There are many ways to accomplish the task of having a sepcific url forward to another url.

1. There are URL rewritting ISAPI addons for IIS, like ISAPI_Rewrite. ISAPI_Rewrite will have a httpd.ini file either in the ISAPI_Rewrite installation folder or the physical folder for the website.
2. II6 has the ability to redirect a request for a folder or a file to another location. This is configured by viewing the properties for the folder or file in the IIS Admin. On the Directory/File tab you will see 3 radio buttons, one of which is "A redirection to a URL".
3. The file can physically exists and in it is code to redirect the user.

Comment: I was sorry but later i got discover that there exists a physical file abc_11.asp as mentioned above. Now it has been solved. They are not using url_write or any other but created a physical file dynamically n called a function of another file while the physical path is called.

Thanks all for help.

Answer (score 0):

If non of mike's suggestions match your setup it's also possible to accomplish the redirection using a custom 404 error page.

- See what is specified for 404 in IIS for the website on the "Custom Errors" tab
- If the type is "URL" rather than "File" then I'd say there's a good chance that code in the file that the URL specifies is performing the redirection