# How do I redirect url to a specific page in IIS6 webserver

Tags: asp-classic, url-rewriting, iis-6

I have a site hosted on IIS6 server. All the pages with specific url (e.g http//www.example.com/products/my-product-name_11.asp ) are redirected to http://www.example.com/product.asp.

but from where it is happening i dont know. So in order to change it what should i do?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537635/iis-server-redirect-locations

Comment: @KoolKabin:  You already have an outstanding question on this subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using http://www.seoconsultants.com/tools/headers.asp on your URL and see if there is any 301 redirects.

Comment: The pages are redirecting. But i would like to know which setting in server made it redirecting?